# MobX 'this' is undefined in setter action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, mobx, mobx-react

I am using a recent create-react-app setup with JS and the `mobx` `decorate` method.

```
import { observable, action, decorate } from 'mobx'

class UserStore {
  users = []
  currentUser = {}

  setUsers(value) {
    this.users = value
  }
}

decorate(UserStore, {
  users: observable,
  currentUser: observable,
  setUsers: action
})

export default UserStore
```

I can use the store and read the empty `users` and `currentUser` observables, but when I try using the `setUsers` action I receive the following error:

`TypeError: Cannot set property 'users' of undefined`

It looks like `this` in undefined, but this is the common way most MobX tutorials show and should not throw an error...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When using MobX with vanilla JavaScript, different contexts can be a bit confusing... MobX introduced [bound `action`s](https://mobx.js.org/actions.html#actionbound) to make this easier.

The correct decorate using `action.bound` would be:

```
setUsers: action.bound
```

OR we can use lambda functions to make sure the context is correct:

```
setUsers = value => {
  this.users = value
}
```

Either change will ensure the context of the setter function is correct and can use the class `this`. Check out the [answers to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54124654/1139105) for more detailed explanations.

Comment: 2021 here ! The link from the answer is broken. Here [the new one](https://mobx.js.org/actions.html#actionbound)